# Angular 5+ are Observable.forkJoin and Observable chaining parallel operations?

Tags: angular, asynchronous, parallel-processing, observable

I have two different implementations of two httpClient requests in angular 5..

in one approach, I have a http request inside a method, in which I do again a second(nested) http request inside the .subscribe() method to another table to retrieve data from two different tables:

```
this.http.get<any>(someUrl, {observe: 'response'}
  ).subscribe(fp_resp => {
  if (fp_resp.status === 200) {
    this.predictionData = this.chart_PrognoseService.formatData(fp_resp.body);
}

    this.http.get<any>(anotherUrl, {observe: 'response'}
    ).subscribe(resp => {
      if (resp.status === 200) {
          this.chart_LoadFactorService.computeLoadFactors(fp_resp.body, resp.body);
      } else {
        console.log('error bei verbindung');
      }
    });
```

In my other approach, I am using Observable.forkJoin to execute the two requests separately in their own method and "joining" the results together:

```
  getBoth() {
    return Observable.forkJoin([this.getFirstData,this.getSecondData])
    .subscribe(data => {
      this.dataArray.push(data[0], data[1]);
      console.log("Daten:", this.dataArray)
    });
  }
```

**My question now is: In my first approach, are the http requests still executed async, which means kind of "in parallel"? Or are they not because I executed one request inside the other? And are the two requests executed in parallel when I use forkJoin?** 
Which approach is better?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> In my first approach, are the http requests still executed async, which means kind of "in parallel"? Or are they not because I executed one request inside the other?

They are executed in series, anything else isn't possible both logically and from how the language works: the function is only called once the first request has been executed.

> And are the two requests executed in parallel when I use forkJoin?

Yes, forkJoin will subscribe to observables in parallel, which means the requests will be executed in parallel.

> Which approach is better?

Whether you need to do things in series or can do it in parallel depends on whether the second request relies on the result of the first, and just generally on the use-case.

That said, nesting subscriptions is considered an anti-pattern in rxjs. If you want to do things in series, you should make use of other operators such as switchMap, mergeMap, concatMap, … depending on your usecase. Here's a simple prototypical example of executing two things in series:

```
this.http.get(/* first request */).pipe(
  switchMap(result1 => this.http.get(/* second request */))
).subscribe(result2 => {
  // …
});
```